# Django override only SplitDateTimeField's timefield into select field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

i am trying to limit `DateTimeField`'s `TimeField` into select field with following options `06:00`, `11:00`, `16:00`. So far i tried `formfield_overrides` and end up with this.

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.DateTimeField: {'widget': SplitDateTimeWidget(
        time_attrs={"choices":settings.FEATURE_HOURS}
    )}
}
```

I was wondering if i override `SplitDateTimeWidget`'s `MultiWidget` wrapper. Or can i extend `SplitDateTimeWidget` and override all the default behavior and achieve what i want? if yes, how can i ?

Answer (score -1):

Well, i created custom class that extends `admin.widgets.AdminSplitDateTime` and use it in `formfield_overrides`

```
class CustomAdminSplitDateTime(admin.widgets.AdminSplitDateTime):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        time_widget = forms.Select(choices=settings.FEATURE_HOURS)
        forms.MultiWidget.__init__(self,  [admin.widgets.AdminDateWidget, time_widget], attrs)
```

and use it in `admin` class like this:

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.DateTimeField: {'widget': CustomAdminSplitDateTime()}
}
```

And thus `FEATURE_HOURS` tuple must be a time objects.